# Is there a PHP security risk in just reading & displaying table data?

Tags: php, security

(Assume there is nothing sensitive/private in the table.)

My code only has a few types functions so far: mysqli_connect, and a SELECT query. As far as I can tell, there is no user input and therefore no security threat, right?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("--", "--", "--", "--");
mysqli_query($con, "set names 'utf8'");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM documents");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {//display info in table}
```

Now one step further. I am using a $_GET variable, which could be edited by a hacker in the navigation bar.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];    
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM document_$id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {//display info in another table}
```

Is there a security threat here? If so, could I eliminate the threat by first ensuring that $_GET['id'] is an integer?

Comment: the second query looks suspicious to me..

Comment: You must filter $_GET['id']. Here is the possiblity of sql injection. Whether you must check it as integer or you can use mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @RutushaJoshi — Using POST won't help. Using encryption won't help.

Comment: Don’t do this. You don’t know what sensitive data is in your database. Even exposing columns like the ID can bite you in the butt if it’s an API, as someone can then just scrape your data by incrementing the ID. Also exposes your database’s schema, any foreign keys and their values (i.e. user IDs). Also, if you make it dynamic (in your case, table name being a variable) then people can read tables you don’t want them to, i.e. the users table, or a settings/system table etc. Just please don’t do this.